# Powerpoint 07 to dvd

Tags: microsoft-office, dvd, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

A friend asked me to make a powerpoint presentation and wants to put a dvd(20 dvds so people can bring them home) in a dvd player and have it play a presentation.
The presentation has looping audio and looping slides that do not coincide.If I stop when the music stops half the slides get cut. If I stop slides from looping music will be cut.

Some problems from googling that I found were dvd authorization.
Some options I have found were to just manually capture about 3 hours of powerpoint to at least get the formatting issues out of the way and at least turn the presentation into a video file that errs so rarely nobody will care.
I have also heard newer powerpoints like 2010 have dvd conversion and I can get that converted at a library but not burned.

questions

will 2010 solve the formatting issue

will 2010 solve the authorization issue

will 2010 create a file I can burn en mass at home with win10

if the answer to any of these is no then what steps do I take without spending money on software that hasn't seen upkeep in nearly a decade

Comment: Do you have copyright to the music? To the visuals?

Comment: It's "Authoring". Yes, PowerPoint can export Videos. You can easily loop it on a DVD. But what do you mean by "does not coincide"?

Comment: @Xavierjazz i do not have the copyright to the music, the visuals are just a home slide show.

Comment: @DanielB there are 167 slides which animate every 5 seconds for 13.92 mins. the songs together are around 21.5  mins saved as one mp3. when the slides loop it's just above halfway done with the music the friend wants to kind of just have it in the background during an event and wants every song to play. got that working fine in powerpoint but i dont know if the easy 2010 way will make the dvd player know to loop or if i have to capture it(would use nvidia shadow-play to record)

Comment: Looping sound and video separately will be quite a challenge, if possible at all, on a regular Video DVD. And like I said, PowerPoint can create videos itself, no need for workarounds using a screen recorder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a screen recording software to record the presentation, use softwares like iMovie to edit it, and burn the movie with whatever app you like.

But honestly, it'd be better if your friends see you do the presentation in front of the screen, so maybe use a DV to record it.

And finally, this is really a elementary question. (Do you know that Apple keynote can export to movie? )

Comment: Judging from the original question (it mentions Powerpoint 07) and the option of using PPT 2010, I'd think that Andrew's using Windows, not Mac, so Keynote and iMovie wouldn't be relevant solutions (unless a Mac is also available).

Comment: "will 2010 create a file I can burn en mass at home with win10". also the presentation is essentially a slide show with music

Comment: One approach: save the presentation as a series of JPG or PNG images (File, Save As, Choose JPG/PNG).  Bring the images into Windows Live Movie Maker or the equivalent, import your soundtrack also, time the slide changes to match the soundtrack, then save the project for DVD.  The program should be able to burn a DVD for you.